# How can i forcefully redirect http request to https in passenger standalone with aws elastic load balancer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, passenger, elastic-load-balancer

I used passenger standalone for my app. currently my app is running on both http and https . i want to redirect all http request to https. I used load balancer in my application. 
I read this articles

> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/
>
> https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template
>
> http://code.eklund.io/blog/2015/03/17/managing-rewrites-for-a-rails-app-on-heroku-with-nginx-plus-phusion-passenger/

i tried this 2 methods

1)

```
 if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { 
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
        }
```

2)

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$REQUEST_URI permanent;
  }
```

i tried all process in same way. but every time it goes in to infinite loop and before i start passenger the instance terminate itself and create new instance because of too many request timeout.

I can't figure out, whether it is issue of elastic load balancer or passenger config. I think when i stop passenger and user try to access app. the request time out generated and due to that new instance created. i am not sure.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Based on some previous issues with https, I've found that in NGINX configuration you have to add:
`proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;`

However, if you edit your post and show us your NGINX configuration we might be able to help you more.

Comment: @RocKhalil I don't have passenger + NGINX  , i used Passenger Standalone. So i don't have nginx config. i only have passenger standalone config which is in erb format.

Comment: oh okay. I usually use puma and NGINX; sorry that didn't help :-)

Comment: Are you using a network load balancer, application load balancer or classic load balancer in ELB?

Comment: @CamdenNarzt classic load balancer

Comment: OK that looks like you are doing things right, can you provide the logs from passenger when the problem occurs?

Comment: @CamdenNarzt When i  stop passenger and restart the server, the passenger shut down automatically. currently i have not log,  I think when i stop passenger and user try to access app. the request time out generated and due to that new instance created.  because some time after i stop passenger, the passenger shut down automatically .  i have one question, passenger and load balancer is different thing . right ? does it relate ?

Comment: Yes they are different. Your ELB load balancer distributes incoming network requests to a group of EC2 instances which all run Passenger. Passenger in turn spins up a number of ruby processes running your app, and distributes the requests that it receives to these ruby processes. So Passenger is a different kind of load balancer, operating at the server level instead of the network level.

Comment: What is the output of `curl -I http://your.domain.here.tld`

Comment: `curl -I http://app.singaporeswimming.com`

`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`
`Cache-Control: no-cache`
`Content-Length: 105`
`Content-Type: text/html`
`Date: Fri, 17 Nov 2017 04:54:54 GMT`
`Location: http://app.singaporeswimming.com/manage`
`Server: nginx/1.8.0 + Phusion Passenger 5.0.14`
`Status: 301 Moved Permanently`
`X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.14`
`X-Rack-CORS: preflight-hit; no-origin`
`X-Request-Id: dd0db076-c687-48dc-be1a-28b369a3f2b0`
`X-Runtime: 0.001350`
`Connection: keep-alive`
`

Comment: @CamdenNarzt Please check my comment

Comment: check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--ssl-port-ssl_port

Comment: The http->https redirect is not happening, instead another redirect is being returned. Can you post the nginx config template you are using? Also like @puneet18 said, be sure to use the ssl options such as `ssl_port`, `ssl_certificate`, and `ssl_certificate_key`.

Comment: @puneet18 @CamdenNarzt Here is the file `https://textb.org/t/vishal/`  . i exactly used this `https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template` . @puneet18, yes i also used all ssl certificate e.g `passenger start -p 80 --ssl --ssl-certificate /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt --ssl-certificate-key /etc/ssl/app.singaporeswimming.key --ssl-port 443 -d -e production`

Comment: @CamdenNarzt Did you checked my comment ?

Comment: That template is out of date, if that's what you got from running `cp $(passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb nginx.conf.erb` then you need to update Passenger.

Comment: i take n from this official site, and it is not out of date 
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

Comment: @vishal yes it is, look at https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/stable-5.1/resources/templates/standalone/config.erb it's not the same as what you have at https://textb.org/t/vishal/.

Comment: @CamdenNarzt yes, i also tried this, but it is giving me syntax error , for `include_passenger_internal_template` . i tried all the code of that file, is it version issue ?  passenger version is `Phusion Passenger version 5.0.14` .

Comment: Exactly, you should be using Passenger 5.1.12.

Comment: @CamdenNarzt Okay , i will update the version of Passenger and will late you know, what happen next. thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @CamdenNarzt Finally i updated the version of passenger. gem version of passenger is `5.3.3` and installed passenger system `Phusion Passenger version 4.0.53` . i forgot where to write that if condition :( . can you help me out ?

Answer (score 2):

I hope your all certificates are installed correctly and pointing to the right path. If not check the below configuration

**Passenger.json**

```
{
  "environment": "production",
  "instance_registry_dir": "/var/run/passenger-instreg",
  "daemonize": true,
  "user": "myappuser",
  "port": 443,
  "ssl": true,
  "ssl_certificate": "/path/to/ssl_cert.pem",
  "ssl_certificate_key": "/path/to/ssl_key.pem",
  "nginx_config_template": "/path/to/nginx.conf.erb"
}
```

You need to use the same configuration which you use for nginx for redirecting from http to https

```
http {
     server_tokens off;
        server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

            # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
             return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     }
```

**Latest Link**
Here is the configuration of standalone passenger to redirect from http to https [latest_link](https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-docs/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/ruby-passenger/https-redirect-load-balanced-ruby-passenger/https-redirect-ruby-passenger.config)

Please refer this [link](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/prod_ssl.html)

Comment: when i applied your solution, the passenger shutdown automatically. whenever i try to stop and start passenger , the passenger shutdown itself. and new instance create multiple times. i don't what is the exact issue.

Comment: In my staging server, i didn't applied load balancer. and this config applied successfully in staging, the http request redirect to https,  but on my live server it is not working because of load balancer may be .

Comment: One more thing, i think the port  value should be 80 and the  ssl-port value will  be 443 .

Comment: I am also giving you another link regarding the configuration of standalone passenger it may help you.

Comment: I didn't use `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` :( .  when i copy the passenger config.erb file, it is giving me this code https://textb.org/t/vishal/ . should i update the whole file with this code https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/prod_ssl.html . because i already tried in past. but it was giving me syntax error for `include_passenger_internal_template` this command.

Comment: You don't have to copy the entire file. You only need to copy the redirect part from that file

Comment: than it is doing the same thing again and again. automatic shut down of passenger . and create new instance without redirecting the http to https.

Comment: Hey, i updated version of passenger, but forgot where to add https line. can you help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at the proxy level, or at the app level. To do it at the app level:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
...
config.force_ssl = true
...
```

Comment: I tried it at first time, but because of load balancer , it is going in infinite loop.

Comment: This will result in an infinite loop and finally fail  as Vishal has pointed out

Comment: "at the proxy level, _or_ at the app level"

Redirecting at both will, indeed, cause a redirect loop.